# To find valid argument for a function in R's help document (meaning of ...)

Tags: r, function, arguments

This question may seem basic but this has bothered me quite a while. The help document for many functions has `...` as one of its argument, but somehow I can never get my head around this `...` thing.

For example, suppose I have created a model say `model_xgboost` and want to make a prediction based on a dataset say `data_tbl` using the `predict()` function, and I want to know the syntax. So I look at its help document which says:

```
?predict

**Usage**
predict (object, ...)

**Arguments**
object      a model object for which prediction is desired.
...         additional arguments affecting the predictions produced.
```

To me the syntax and its examples didn't really enlighten me as I still have no idea what the valid syntax/arguments are for the function. In an online course it uses something like below, which works:

```
data_tbl %>%
    predict(model_xgboost, new_data = .)
```

However, looking across the help doc I cannot find the `new_data` argument. Instead it mentioned `newdata` argument in its **Details** section, which actually didn't work if I displace the `new_data = .` with `newdata = .`:

```
Error in `check_pred_type_dots()`:
! Did you mean to use `new_data` instead of `newdata`?
```

My questions are:

1. How do I know exactly what argument(s) / syntax can be used for a function like this?
2. Why `new_data` but not `newdata` in this example?
3. I might be missing something here, but is there any reference/resource about how to use/interpret a help document, in plain English? (a lot of document, including R help file seem just give a brief sentence like "*additional arguments* affecting the predictions produced" etc)

Comment: the what is in `...` is specific to the logic of the given function, and the additional 'inputs' it takes. Consider in terms of `mean(`, where oftentimes `na.rm` is the difference between a useful answer or not.so, `<- lapply(my_df$col, mean, na.rm == TRUE)`, where here `...` are (some of)  the arguments that mean accepts. This can be extended to any function you are considering, and multiple further arguments can be included, if they are allowed by the given function and separated by `,`, Best (or only) done, in the `...` in the order they are listed/mentioned in help for the function...

Comment: Read the documentation in any "Introduction to R"  source you trip across.   It's really not that obscure.

Answer (score 3):

@CarlWitthoft's answer is good, I want to add a little bit of nuance about this particular function.  The reason the help page for `?predict` is so vague is an unfortunate consequence of the fact that `predict()` is a *generic method* in R: that is, it's a function that can be applied to a variety of different object types, using slightly different (but appropriate) methods in each case. As such, the `?predict` help page only lists `object` (which is required as the first argument in all methods) and `...`, because different predict methods could take very different arguments/options.

If you call `methods("predict")` in a clean R session (before loading any additional packages) you'll see a list of 16 methods that base R knows about.  After loading `library("tidymodels")`, the list expands to 69 methods.  I don't know what class your object is (`class("model_xgboost")`), but assuming that it's of class `model_fit`, we look at `?predict.model_fit` to see

> ```
>  predict(object, new_data, type = NULL, opts = list(), ...)
> ```

This tells us that we need to call the new data `new_data` (and, reading a bit farther down, that it needs to be "A rectangular data object, such as a data frame")

The help page for `predict` says

> **Most** prediction methods which are similar to those for linear
> models have an argument ‘newdata’ specifying the first place to
> look for explanatory variables to be used for prediction

(emphasis added). I don't know why the `parsnip` authors (the `predict.model_fit` method comes from the `parsnip` package) decided to use `new_data` rather than `newdata`, presumably in line with the [tidyverse style guide](https://style.tidyverse.org/syntax.html), which says

> Use underscores (_) (so called snake case) to separate words within a name.

In my opinion this might have been a mistake, but you can see that the parsnip/tidymodels authors have realized that people are likely to make this mistake and added an informative warning, as shown in your example and noted e.g. [here](https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/issues/525)

Comment: Yeah, nothing like a good flame war over  `new_data` vs. `newdata`  vs.  `newData` vs. `new.Data`   :-)

Answer (score 0):

Among other things,  the existence of `...` in a function definition means you can enter **any** arguments (values, functions, etc) you want to.  There are some cases where the main function does not even use the `...` but passes them to functions called inside the main function.  Simple example:

```
foo <- function(x,...){
y <- x^2
plot(x,y,...)
}
```

I know of functions which accept a function as an input argument, at which point the items to include via `...`  are specific to the selected input function name.